# linkerd cli returns "invalid argument" when running "top"

Tags: kubernetes, linkerd

I'm going through the [getting-started](https://linkerd.io/2/getting-started/) tutorial for `linkerd` and I've got `stable-2.1.0` installed on kube `v1.9.6` and `v1.12.3`

I've validated that all the pods are running and the mesh is working via the dashboard.

When I try to run `linkerd -n linkerd top deploy/linkerd-web` in step 4, I get `invalid argument` back from the controller.

Here's the verbose output:

```
DEBU[0000] Expecting API to be served over [https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/linkerd/services/linkerd-controller-api:http/proxy/api/v1/]
DEBU[0000] Making gRPC-over-HTTP call to [https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/linkerd/services/linkerd-controller-api:http/proxy/api/v1/SelfCheck] []
DEBU[0000] Response from [https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/linkerd/services/linkerd-controller-api:http/proxy/api/v1/SelfCheck] had headers: map[Content-Type:[application/octet-stream] Date:[Wed, 12 Dec 2018 05:54:06 GMT] Content-Length:[108]]
DEBU[0000] gRPC-over-HTTP call returned status [200 OK] and content length [108]
DEBU[0003] Response from [https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/linkerd/services/linkerd-controller-api:http/proxy/api/v1/TapByResource] had headers: map[Content-Type:[application/octet-stream] Date:[Wed, 12 Dec 2018 05:54:09 GMT]]
Error: invalid argument
```

Any advice on what I should try next?

I also created this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/1976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are some dependencies (termbox) for drawing the top table that aren't supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux. Here's the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/1976